# Machine Learning - Same impurity values

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

Imagine this example:

[image: Atributes table]

We see that the attributes `color` and `points` have the same value. What attribute should we choose for the construction of the tree?

Comment: See the answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/166971/97464

Answer (score -1):

A decision tree will automatically select the attributes that are predictive of the targets. The automatic learning of meaningful features is one the primary advantages of machine learning in general and decision tree in particular.